# .htaccess for site migration

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

We are migrating to a new server structure and I need some help with htaccess. I'm a php programmer and by no means an apache expert.

Here is the plain explanation:

- I need the root directory of www.oldsite.com to redirect to the root directory www.newsite.com.
- A specific directory www.oldsite/dir1 to redirect to a subdomain on the new site as in newdomain.newsite.com
- Everything else www.oldsite.com/whatever/ needs to go to apps.newsite.com/whatever/

What I have right now is:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule / http://www.newsite.com [L,R=301]
RewriteRule (.*)dir1/ http://newdomain.newsite.com [L,R=301]
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://apps.newsite.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

But its not working as I want it to...

Anyway, any and all help will be appreciated.

Thanks, 
-Orallo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using mod_alias, you can put this in either server/vhost config or in your htaccess file (**in your document root of the oldsite.com**):

```
Redirect 301 /dir1 http://newdomain.newsite.com
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(.+)$ http://apps.newsite.com/$1
RedirectMatch 301 ^/$ http://www.newsite.com
```

As for mod_rewrite, you need to remove the leading slashes from your rewrite rules since you are using them in an htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.newsite.com [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^dir1/(.*) http://newdomain.newsite.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ http://apps.newsite.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: One more question, I just got word that now mgmt wants the root dir to serve the index of the old domain instead of sending to the newsite? I removed www.newsitec.com and replaced it with /index.php, but it redirects with the third rule to apps.newsite.com.  Is there a way to stop that?

Comment: Also, I just realized if I leave out the trailing / in dir1 on the 2nd rule, the redirect falls throuhg to the 3rd rule and goes to apps.newsite.com/dir1 instead of newdomain.newsite.com :-O

Comment: @orallo Try changing the first rule to: `RewriteRule ^(index\.php)?$ http://www.newsite.com [L,R=301]`

Answer (score 0):

Your first rewrite was causing your problem, basically redirecting everything.

This should do what you want:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://www.newsite.com [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^/?dir1/(.*) http://newdomain.newsite.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ http://apps.newsite.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

I would suggest putting this set of rewrite rules in the actual Apache conf file for this host and turning off `AllowOverride`, as it will give better performance.  Since you are in essence no longer using the web directory for the old site, there is no reason to make the Apache server look in that directory (and any other child directories that may still be there) to find .htaccess files.

Comment: THanks to you too Mike, as you can see both are very similar and I tried this configuration too and it works perfectly too.